# I want to update records of 2 tables in Database based on matching Key

Tags: java, sql, plsql, triggers, db2

I have 2 tables, Source and Target as below,

### Source

```
Key | Source_ID | Target_ID | Source_Data
-----------------------------------------
1     s1          null        some_source_data
2     s2          null        some_source_data
```

### Target

```
Key | Source_ID | Target_ID | Target_Data
-------------------------------------------
1     null        t1          some_target_data
2     null        t2          some_target_data
```

Initially Source Table has existing records, and inserting records to Target table freshly
Now my requirement is to update the records of Target_ID from Target Table and Source_ID from Source Table based on Key matching, As of now I am doing it on java, by joining these two tables using Key Column and hold the result in Result Set and execute update query for both the table one by one, its working quite well in case of less number of data, but in case of large amount of data Java execution is taking a huge time for 200000 records on each table took 2 hours to complete the operation, now I want it to move out of java and do it in SQL only like a trigger or PL/SQL, on inserting the records in Target Table these Trigger or Script should run automatically and do the Job what am doing java, need your help/suggestion on how to implement this, Am using DB2 Database

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is to create a trigger on your source_Table that updates target_id in your target_table.

That should do the trick:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_targettable
AFTER UPDATE ON source_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE target_table SET target_id = :NEW.source_id WHERE key = :NEW.key
END;
```

So let´s say you make an update on your Source Table.

```
UPDATE SOURCE_TABLE SET SOURCE_ID = s1 where key = 1;
```

This will automatically set your target_table.target_id to the same value as in source_table.source_id where the keys are matching.

I hope that is what you need. Otherwise please specify your question.

I recommend [reading](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple `join`:

```
select s.key, s.source_id, t.target_id, s.source_data, t.target_data
from source s join
     target t
     on s.key = t.key;
```

If you want this available *on demand*, you can wrap this logic in a view.  For performance, you can add indexes on the `key` columns in each table.  You *could* also create a materialized view, but with indexes that seems like overkill.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your comment, but I hope you didn't read my question properly, I want to update Source Table and Target Tables Data based on Key, currently I am using join to do this operation in Java, but I want to do it in SQL using some trigger or PL/SQL

Comment: @RAJUGORAI . . . Why bother?  The `join` is simple enough and should have good performance.  Also, "java" doesn't update tables in a database.  `UPDATE` statements (or `MERGE`) do the updates.

Comment: Updating all records is my requirement, and the table I mentioned is just a sample, these are huge tables, and in Java I am updating records using UPDATE Query only, and its taking hell lot of time when the records are more than a lakh, so have to write a Trigger to update all records in both the tables once new records inserted in Target Table

Comment: @rajugorai.. why you insist on trigger ? If I understood you, your first requirement is clear about passing the key from somewhere and then matching to both the tables but what exactly you are trying to update?